# How: Convert separate Date & Time text strings together into a single unified Date Time field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

How: Convert separate Date & Time text strings together into a single unified Date Time field?

Taking the following text pasted into an Excel file from a web page:

Column A

[image]

What formula would be needed to pull both of those together into a Cell as a Combined: Date-Time
Data

Column B (I typed the following manually, but how could I automate this with a formula)?

[image]

Been unable to use the VALUE() and DATEVALUE() on the above string in A1

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/

Answer (score 2):

remove the Day name and add the time:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,99)+A2
```

Then format the result cell: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am copy pasting the above from Amazon and other Tracking for packages websites hence wondering if it can be done without having to format the cells? No way for it to default appear such?

Comment: Sure but it will be a text field: `=TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,99)+A2,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")` which may slow down and error if referred to in other formula.

Comment: Scott - It seems to be working great, even when pulled in by another date time math formula using INT(X-Y)

Comment: It was working great in Office 2010, but when I opened the same file in Excel 2016/19 - it borks. Any way to fix that?